# Power of vote depending on reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, voting

I'm talking about the power of voting. Idea is to add additional weight to vote from those users that have more reputation. Say, if user with reputation more than 1k votes +1 for answer, actually it would give +2 and so on. Hope, my idea is clear. To my mind, it would increase relevance of answers that deserves attention and should be accepted. Sometimes I see completely wrong answers that users votes for just because they might look correct or have appeared first. That's pity. Moreover, sometimes less complete answers are accepted instead of more useful.

So, what do you think of this?

Comment: @Ams that's an interesting idea, though I'm not sure how it would work in practice. I definitely agree about the wrong answers... But, there are many new users who dont have the rep yet simply because they are new here, even though they may be xperts in their field much more than other users with higher rep. So, that wouldnt solve anything either...

Comment: Btw, although its cool to discuss this here, ultimately its pointless - All StackExchange sites work the same way. If you want to change any of the mechanisms, or suggest a network-wide feature, it would eventually have to go to [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) anyway...

Comment: @AviD, yep, that is true about new users - also was thinking of this. Unfortunately, reputation does not always guarantee that what we would like to see. However, this could solve problem at least at some level. I just thought to involve others minds here to improve my idea - to discuss and suggest alternatives and improvements. If idea would look capable of living, then it would be worth to implement it in other sites as well, because situation I am worried about is not only about IT security.

Comment: The biggest problem is that the chosen answers are out-dated or just not as good as other answers, or just poorly chosen, and only the posts' author can change that (and they **rarely** do). Those chosen answers are "stuck" to the top and might confuse others or simply waste a person's time. voting should stay democratic. this system is fair to everyone. Imagine a person with a degree has more voting power i his country then a one without... riots.